# CreateMap error where there is a null value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have the following mapping:

```
        CreateMap<Logo, KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
            .ConvertUsing(s => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(s.LogoID, s.LogoName));

        CreateMap<Project, ProjectDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Logo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Logo));
```

Here are the models:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int      ProjectID       { get; set; }
    public string   Name            { get; set; }
    public virtual  Logo Logo { get; set; }
}

public class Logo
{
    [Key]
    public int    LogoID { get; set; }
    public string LogoName { get; set; }
    public byte[] LogoContent { get; set; }
    public string LogoContentType { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectDTO : BaseDTO<ProjectDTO, Project>
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<int, string> Logo { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, in my ProjectDTO I don't want all details of Logo but only the keypair logoID, logoName.

It works when I have logo attached to my project. But I got a runtime error when there is no logo attached. The errors is on the CreateMap ...ConvertUsing line.

Any idea how can I avoid CreateMap error when I don't have any logo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int      ProjectID       { get; set; }
    public string   Name            { get; set; }
    private Logo _logo = new Logo();
    public virtual  Logo Logo 
          { get {return _logo;} set{_logo = value;} }
}
```

But Your code would still fail if many of your Projects do not have a logo and the same key might get inserted again in the map i.e. LogoID as 0.

I would certainly think about re factoring the code a bit maybe get rid of the Logo Map.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
        CreateMap<Project, ProjectDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Logo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Logo == null ? null : src.Logo));
```